# Is there a script language to build neural networks, with some graphics capabilities?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I have just seen this incredible video in which we can see AI-controlled preys and predators, mutation, genetic succession, and how their population change as they evolve: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwrp3lB-jkQ

But it's based on C++. Taking Pine Script as an example, is there a scripting language that makes building such simulations easier, without the requirement of knowing C languages?

Comment: Tool recommendation requests are off-topic here; see #3 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you might be more interested in [Evolutionary Computation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_computation) and [Genetic Algorithms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) more than ANNs but these fields cross over in the field of [Neuroevolution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroevolution).

Taking pinescript out of the equation for the moment - [Tensorflow.js](https://www.tensorflow.org/js) is an approachable web based framework to start working with ML models, depending on your feeling - you may or may not consider javascript a scripting language, but the learning curve is not as steep as c++.

I’d recommend having a look at the [TF Playground](http://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=tanh&batchSize=10&dataset=circle&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=4,2&seed=0.60631&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false) for a tour for interactive ML sims using this framework.